# How to parse the default css property to inline style attribute

Tags: jquery, css, html

At the moment I have a page where users can create divs and drag/drop them into another div `id="holder"`.

I have a save button that gets the html of holder. `$('#Holder').html();`

The divs in holder have some styling from a CSS file and inline styling: `style="left:10px; right:10px; background-color:#000000;"` added by jQuery.

What I want is to combine the styling from my CSS file with the inline styling so I am able to use `$('#holder').html();` and have all styles.

Question: How can I parse the CSS styling into the `style=""` attr.

So after the info an example of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/Ub9ZD/

As you can see im missing the width, height and position style.

== EDIT ==

After looking at given link I'm still stuggling with this.

I still can't combine the inline style and CSS style from file.

Progress: http://jsfiddle.net/Ub9ZD/39/

Comment: Here's the answer for your same question asked ~3 years ago: [little link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5830517/364869).

Comment: this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: @Abody97 @loler Still not quite my answer. Above function take only from the given `#holder` but I need also the children of this `#holder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not as easy as it sounds, not by a long shot. If you want to look at an object's CSS properties, you can use the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function jQuery provides. Essentially, you'd retrieve each of the element's styles via the `.css()` function and reapply them to the element with the `htmlELement.style` method. Then, theoretically, `.html()` would give you a list of all the CSS styles on that element.

Are you sure that's what you need, or can you just use `.css()` the way it's intended?